# Windows 7 / 8 stop modal dialogue flash on parent focus

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, default-settings

Is there some setting in Windows where I can change the default behavior that causes the border and title of a modal dialogue box to flash like 6 or 7 times when I click on the parent window?

Simply focusing it would be plenty to let me know what I did was wrong.

I don't feel the need for all the sirens and bull horns and strobe lights to let me know I clicked in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
   ```
3. Locate the `ForegroundFlashCount` value, and set it to `1`.

   **Note** In case the value is missing, create a new `DWORD` (32-bit) value. While you *could* set it to `0`, that would prevent modal dialog boxes from properly regaining focus.
4. Log off and log back on to apply the changes.

### Additional information

The `ForegroundFlashCount` registry value was first introduced with Windows 2000. Here's an excerpt from the original documentation:

> Specifies the number of times the taskbar button flashes to notify the user that the system has activated a background window.
>
> <sub>Source: [ForegroundFlashCount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957205.aspx)</sub>

In Windows Vista and earlier the value was set to `3` by default. Starting with Windows 7, the default value is `7`. Although it doesn't seem to be specified anywhere, the same value also controls the way modal dialog boxes flash when you try to shift the focus to their parent windows.